# P is undecidable and not semidecidable, Q is undecidable and semidecidable and P ⊂ Q

Tags: formal-languages, decidable

My problem: Define two sets P and Q of words (that is, two problems) such that:
P is undecidable and not semidecidable, Q is undecidable and semidecidable and P ⊂ Q

Comment: You should ask this at http://cs.stackexchange.com/ or http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One example of such sets:

Define Q as the set of turing machines, which halt on empty input. Define P as the set of turing machines, which halt on every input.

Clearly P ⊂ Q and P is undecidable and not semidecidable, but Q is undecidable and semidecidable.

Comment: Thanks but why P ⊂ Q ?

Comment: Because a turing machine, which halts on every input, obviously also halts on empty input.